# Where are located Excel button icons?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, icons, file-location

I have made my own excel button icon, in ms paint, for my personal macro.
It is .png format.
When I will be renaming my macro group cart, I will change macro's icon.

Comment: Do you want to place the icon in the ribbon or someplace else?

Comment: I know how add icons into ribbon or into top up window ribbon. I need to place my file in a location, which will be available to detect by excel icon gallery; so I will be able pick it from popped-up window.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is to create an addin with a customui ribbon interface.  In the addin, which is loaded when Excel is loaded will contain the picture you want.